# Node.js on nginx + Cent OS7 shows blank page or ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: node.js, linux, nginx, centos

**Symptom**

I think I've messed up my domain/nginx settings. The server shows up properly for 70~60% of time but sometimes it shows blank page(no html at all) or `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` page.

the url is: [sungryeol.com](http://sungryeol.com)

I've checked both Stackoverflow and Node.js + CentOS 7 + nginx setup tutorials on Google(which leads to digital ocean mostly)

**Settings**

Node.js / Express.js

OS: Cent OS 7(Vultr VPS)

Reverse proxy: nginx

DNS: Namecheap

*Namecheap domain setting*

```
Type------------------Host---Value-------------------------------TTL
A Record--------------@------45.32.9.128-------------------------5 min
CNAME Record----------www----sungryeol.com.----------------------5 min
URL Redirect Record---www----http://www.sungryeol.com Unmasked---
```

the dot on sungryeol.com'.' is automatically added by Namecheap UI.

*`nginx` setting*

`nginx -t` shows the configuration has no error. The internal setting has no problem I assume. It works fine with IP address but still shows blank page or redirect error from the URL : `(www).sungryeol.com`.

`/etc/nginx/conf.d`

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    ...
}
```

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
}
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/portfolio.conf`

```
upstream portfolio {
  server 127.0.0.1:3001 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=10s weight=1;
  ip_hash;
  keepalive 512;
}

server
{
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on default_server;
  server_name sungryeol.com www.sungryeol.com;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
  # client_max_body_size 50M;
  index index.html;

  location /
  {
    proxy_pass http://portfolio;
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
  }
}
```

`/etc/nginx/proxy_params`

```
proxy_buffers 16 32k;
proxy_buffer_size 64k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 128k;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
proxy_connect_timeout 59s;
proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 htt$
proxy_no_cache $http_pragma $http_authorization;
proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
proxy_read_timeout 600;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_send_timeout 600;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding '';
proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header Proxy '';
proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Original-Request $request_uri;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

Comment: Why do you have a URL Redirect record?

Comment: I've read it from somewhere it's for redirecting www URL to URL without www. so it is not necessary I guess?

Comment: I have never used it, but it seems to me that your DNS provider is redirecting `www.sungryeol.com` to `www.sungryeol.com`. Also, the record seems to be in direct conflict with your CNAME record.

Comment: Thank you. I'll omit that specific redirection. Since it is hard to reproduce the blank page error and it happens rather arbitrarily, I'll keep my eyes on the webpage for few more days if it happens again and if it doesn't, I'll leave a comment here.

Comment: It's been 2 weeks since adopting the @Richard Smith's opinion. it's been working fine so far. I think that was the answer. having a conflicted/duplicate CNAME record causes blank page errors. Thank you once again!